# Problem with Cocoapods, showing error 'Couldn't determine repo type for URL' when installing pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode13

I used `Cocoapods` a lot, but recently whenever I was updating the pods (`pod update`), it started duplicating files and often didn't let me create a build for the App Store.

I updated Cocoapods to the last version possible but still didn't solve that. Then I tried to remove and re-install it.

Now is occurring another issue. When I try to run `pod install` on any project, pods are not getting installed like previously, but is showing this error:

```
myUser$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`: Permission bits for '/Users/myUser/.netrc' should be 0600, but are 644
```

Previously, this never happened, but now it's happening even on projects that Cocoapods worked like a charm. What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The error message says there's a permission issue:

> Permission bits for '/Users/myUser/.netrc' should be 0600, but are 644

So in order to fix the permission, you should do this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Then try to run `pod install` again. If the root cause was really this permissions issue then everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 0xced's answer: Check and fix possible syntax errors in ~/.netrc .