# Why is my React Native Pod Install Erroring?

Tags: ruby, react-native, chruby, ruby-install

Trying to run pod install in a new React Native project and getting this error. Ruby is installed with brew

I have installed chruby and ruby-install, which I have then used to install ruby-2.7.5 cocopods, ffi and bundler. When trying bundler to install I get this error:

```
warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes/hermes-engine.podspec`
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Permission bits for '/Users/macbook/.netrc' should be 0600, but are 644
```

Answer (score 2):

So I put out a bounty on this because I couldn't figure it out for ages. Until I did. (Hopefully this fix works for everyone else)

First when I ran `xcode-select -p` it was returning `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

However this looked odd as another an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137001/error-installing-cocoapods-dependencies-when-initiating-new-react-native-project) seemed to suggest that maybe this was causing an issue. It ended up that I just hadn't set my CLI tools correctly as described in the [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup). Since it only had one option in the dropdown I assumed that the CLI tools were already set. However when I went back and specifically clicked on the one option, it made changes to my system.

Now running `xcode-select -p` returns `/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

TL;DR : Open Xcode, go to 'Settings...' in the menu bar. Then go to the 'Locations' tab and click on the 'Command Line Tools' dropdown and click on the latest version (click on a version even if it seems like a version is already set). Now try your pod install again!

Answer (score 1):

Probably this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/69427481/8988448) would solve your issue. Looks like you haven't given proper permissions.

run `chmod 600 ~/.netrc` and once it is done, run `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

Got same error as below:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
ℹ Installing dependencies
✔ CocoaPods (https://cocoapods.org/) is not installed. CocoaPods is necessary for the iOS project to run correctly. Do you want to install it? › Yes, with gem (may require sudo)
✔ Installing CocoaPods
✔ Installing Bundler
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

Environment: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

[image]

1. Through `gem` installed cocoapods like below.

`rn sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
Password:

2. When `run react-native init myproj`, choose gem to install coacopods again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello once I also had same issue . I have resolve it.Follow this step it would work .

```
 This error is cause by installing same package multiple time in single project



Try to remove that package from project and reinstall that project.
```

**Try to  uninstall ruby-2.7.5**

**yarn remove package name**

**yarn add package name**

or

**npm uninstall  package name**

**npm install  package name**

and

**cd ios && pod install && cd ..**

**npx react-native run-ios**