# Error Installing CocoaPods dependencies when initiating new React Native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to create new React Native project and it failed due to error of multiple podfiles were found.

```
error: warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same error while creating a new project.

Comment: Specifically React Native 0.70

Comment: Did you find a fix for this. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 15):

Create a file called `react-native.config.js` at the root level of your project with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {
            sourceDir: './ios',
        },
    },
};
```

Then when you run `npx react-native run-ios` the Podfile in the ios/ directory will by chosen and you won't see the error.

Comment: relevant documentation confirming this answer: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/projects.md

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is just me but this was my experience and fix:

First when I ran `xcode-select -p` it was returning `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

However this looked odd as another an answer here seemed to suggest that maybe this was causing an issue. It ended up that I just hadn't set my CLI tools correctly as described in the react native docs. Since it only had one option in the dropdown I assumed that the CLI tools were already set. However when I went back and specifically clicked on the one option, it made changes to my system.

Now running `xcode-select -p` returns

`/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

TL;DR : Open Xcode, go to 'Settings...' in the menu bar. Then go to the 'Locations' tab and click on the 'Command Line Tools' dropdown and click on the latest version (click on a version even if it seems like a version is already set). Now try your pod install again!

Comment: It worked for me. It seems that command line tools is downloaded, listed on xcode but not selected. After selecting it, pod install succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

Same here, below some more details to help solving issue.
Fresh new Macbook Pro (M1 Pro) and after following installation steps from rn docs. Same error when init newest version, also same with 0.69.0 `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`:

```
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

.zshrc

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)
```

"

.zprofile

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

xcode 14

After

```
 ruby --version
 brew info cocoapods
```

i get:

```
    ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3
```

I don't understand why its creating new folder with ruby cocoapods inside my rn project: `/vendor`
Never had that issue on my older M1. I already tried with `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

EDIT 1: `pod install --project-directory=ios` shows me error similar to another [cocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10518#issuecomment-799664862) but didnt fix

**Answer in that issue helped. Try:**

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

It fixed my errors and allowed me to build 0.70.3 rn init.
But before that i've also downgrade my xcode to 13.4, not sure if it was necessary.

But still i get this strange /vendor folder in my rn app, but after deleting it its still building fine on ios.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enabled command line tools in Xcode.
Xcode → settings → Locations → Command line tools

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sreedevi, I did but still same error. :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try - `pod install --project-directory=ios`

Comment: it happens at the initial create react native app and it crash before every folders and files created